# Simple way to make wired internet wireless without router

Tags: internet, ethernet, wifi

Is there any device which you can plug into an Ethernet port and then have it broadcast the internet connection it receives through Ethernet wirelessly with a set password (maybe a serial number on device itself)?

The problem is, I have a Wi-fi capable device, an iPhone and I want to use the wired internet connection in a hotel room, but the iPhone needs a Wi-fi signal. How can I accomplish this with a rather simplistic device.

// EDIT:

Can this be achieved with an [Apple Airport Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/specs.html)?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is indeed a wireless ethernet bridge. However, almost any wireless router can be used in this fashion.

Grab the wifi router you want, should run no more than $50. Plugin power and connect to it for configuration. Change the access password, setup the wireless configuration, and disable DHCP.

Then plug your upstream into one of the LAN ethernet ports rather than the internet port. Instant wireless bridge.

Comment: The problem I have is I don't want to take an extra laptop with, and also, I don't necessarily want to configure the router when we get there. I want something that already has a passkey encoded on it, which I can just plug in, connect to wi-fi network, type in password and use the internet.

Comment: After the initial setup, a wireless bridge just gets plugged in and used. There's no configuration after that point. Just plug into the network, connect to the wireless and go to the world.

Answer (score 1):

An Apple Airport Express can do exactly what you need it todo, however it may have some problems with the way hotel internet normally works, you may have to make sure its in bridging mode, otherwise a laptop can do the same thing by sharing its ethernet connection and creating a wireless network for your iphone to connect to

Comment: Bridge mode is not really an issue the best way for little more privacy is set a NAT masquerading. Else maybe the way hotel is configured it will only allow one IP address per chamber NAT resolve this simply.

Answer (score 1):

An apple's airport express can do do the job as well as any other wireless router. You'll need to configure the router in a browser type: 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1 and follow what you need to.

Comment: Can I preconfigure the passkey at home? Will the Airport remember that passkey? I know I can connect to the Airport via the iPhone, but I really don't want to take a laptop with.

Comment: Yes you should think that the airport is like a computer with it's own static memory. It'll boot when you plug it in the wall and be ready with the previous passphrase set.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion, but I didn't know for sure.

Comment: Can you then choose an answer that fits what you ask as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The device you're describing is called a [wireless ethernet bridge](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/hardwarenetworkgear/ss/wirelessadapter_4.htm).

Unfortunately, it's not simplistic, or cheap.

Comment: Can Apple's Airport Express not accomplish this?

Comment: Sure they're kinda' cheap. I have a 3Com travel router made just for situations like converting a wired hotel connection into a wireless connection. It can also take wireless connections and jack into an old desktop or laptop that only has a wired NIC in it. This particular travel router is a bit old so I don't know how readily available it is, though...